# how to filter element in multiarray with simple way in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have locations multi array and i want to filter one location that matched (country_name,city_name)
if matched two arrays or many..then give me one array only

```
$country = 'United States';
$city = 'Miami';

$locations = 
    Array ( 
    "count" => 6,
    "query" => "Miami",
    "locations" => Array ( 
    "0" => Array ( 
    "id" => 4621 ,
    "name" => "Miami, FL, United States - 661 hotels" ,
    "country_name" => "United States ",
    "country_code" => "US" ,
    "state_code" => "FL" 
    ),
    "1" => Array (
    "id" => 4633 ,
    "name" => "Miami, OK, United States - 86 hotels" ,
    "country_name" =>" United States",
    "country_code" => "US" ,
    "state_code" => "OK" 
        ),
    "2" => Array (
    "id" => 21670 ,
    "name" =>" South Miami, FL, United States - 30 hotels",
    "country_name" => "United States" ,
    "country_code" => "US" ,
    "state_code" => "FL"
        ) 
    )
    );
```

Comment: Do you mean that the results have to go in 1 new array, or that you want to join the results in the $locations array? And are you searching for the $city value in the "query" field or inside the "name" field?

Comment: give me one array like this

Comment: "0" => Array ( 
    "id" => 4621 ,
    "name" => "Miami, FL, United States - 661 hotels" ,
    "country_name" => "United States ",
    "country_code" => "US" ,
    "state_code" => "FL" 
    )

Comment: i search with city in name filed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newArray= array();
foreach ($locations['locations'] as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($value['name'],$city) !== false) {
       if(strpos($value['country_name'],$country) !== false){
            $newArray = $value; 
           break;
       }
    }
}
print_r($newArray);
```

This way I'm returning a new array containing the arrays that have the values you searched for. Is this what you want?

Edited: see if it's the result that you want.

Comment: Which one? The first one that has the right result? In this case replace array_push($newArray, $value); with $newArray = $value; break;

Answer (score 0):

```
$locationArray = $locations['locations'];
foreach($locationArray as $location) {
    if ((strpos($location['country_name'], $country) !== false) && (strpos($location['name'], $country) !== false)) {
        return $location;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function that validates if a item matches your conditions. You can use that function in array_filter() or in a loop.

```
$locations = array( 
  "count" => 6,
  "query" => "Miami",
  "locations" => array( 
    "0" => array( 
      "id" => 4621 ,
      "name" => "Miami, FL, United States - 661 hotels" ,
      "country_name" => "United States ",
      "country_code" => "US" ,
      "state_code" => "FL" 
    ),
    // ...
  )
);

// define the filter function
$country = 'United States';
$city = 'Miami';
$validate = function($item) use ($country, $city) {
  return (
    trim($item['country_name']) == $country &&
    0 === strpos($item['name'], $city.',')
  );
};

// filter
var_dump(
  array_filter($locations['locations'], $validate)
);

// find first
$location = NULL;
foreach ($locations['locations'] as $location) {
  if ($validate($location)) {
    $result = $location;
    break;
  }
}
var_dump($result);
```